# How to do an on-item-changed for an NSPopUpButton?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nspopupbutton

I'm trying to implement a system that changes a label based on the state of an `NSPopUpButton`.
So far I've tried to do what's displayed in the code below, but whenever I run it, the code just jumps into the `else` clause, throwing an alert

```
- (IBAction)itemChanged:(id)sender {
    if([typePopUp.stringValue isEqualToString: @"Price per character"]) {
        _currency = [currencyField stringValue];
        [additionalLabel setStringValue: _currency];

    }
    else if([typePopUp.stringValue isEqualToString: @"Percent saved"]) {
        _currency = additionalLabel.stringValue = @"%";
    }

    else alert(@"Error", @"Please select a calculation type!");
}
```

So does anyone here know what to do to fix this?

Comment: First, what is "typePopup" ? If it is the NSPopUpButton itself, then your on the wrong object. you should use the popup's selection instead (typePopUp.selectedItem.xxxxx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@hamstergene is on the right track, but is comparing the title of the menu item rather than, say, the *tag*, which is wrong for the following reasons:

1. It means you cannot internationalize the app.
2. It introduces the possibility of spelling mistakes.
3. It's an inefficient comparison; comparing every character in a string takes way longer than comparing a single integer value.

Having said all that, `NSPopUpButton` makes it difficult to insert tags into the menu items, so you need to use the index of the selected item:

Assume you create the menu items using:

```
[typePopUp removeAllItems];
[typePopUp addItemsWithTitles: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Choose one...", @"Price per character", @"Percent saved", nil]];
```

Then create an `enum` that matches the order of the titles in the array:

```
typedef enum {
    ItemChooseOne,
    ItemPricePerCharacter,
    ItemPercentSaved
} ItemIndexes;
```

And then compare the selected item index, as follows:

```
- (IBAction)itemChanged:(id)sender {
    NSInteger index = [(NSPopUpButton *)sender indexOfSelectedItem];
    switch (index) {
    case ItemChooseOne:
        // something here
        break;
    case ItemPricePerCharacter:
        _currency = [currencyField stringValue];
        [additionalLabel setStringValue: _currency];
        break;
    case ItemPercentSaved:
        _currency = @"%";               // See NOTE, below
        additionalLabel.stringValue = @"%";
        break;
    default:
        alert(@"Error", @"Please select a calculation type!");
    }
}
```

**NOTE** the following line was incorrect in your code:

```
_currency = additionalLabel.stringValue = @"%";
```

Multiple assignment works because the *result* of `x = y` is `y`.  This is not the case when a setter is involved.  The corrected code is above.

**EDIT** This answer was heavily edited following more info from the OP.

Comment: for the tag system to work, do I need to be aware of the order of the items in it?

Comment: @ElectricCoffee No, I don't see why.  Just ensure the tags are unique within the menu (pop up button).

Comment: I implemented your system, and it yields the exact same result as before, and when I added the tags to the popup button I added them as a string array, not as an enum, does that matter?

Comment: @ElectricCoffee String array?  Tags are integers.

Comment: here's what I did to add the items: `[typePopUp removeAllItems];
    [typePopUp addItemsWithTitles:
     [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
      @"Choose one...", @"Price per character", @"Percent saved", nil]];`

Comment: @ElectricCoffee Ah I see; no you'll need to create each menu item individually so you can assign the tags to each.  I'll edit my answer to show an example of what I think will work.

Comment: @ElectricCoffee OK, edited.  You'll need to use `[NSPopUpButton selectedItemIndex]` and tags play no part.

Comment: xcode reports an error regarding your `[(NSPopUpButton*) sender selectedItemIndex]`... it says there's no such method

Comment: @ElectricCoffee Yeah it should be `indexOfSelectedItem`.

Comment: @ElectricCoffee Good to hear.

Answer (score 2):

To query the title of currently selected item in `NSPopUpButton`:

```
NSMenuItem* selectedItem = [typePopUp selectedItem];
NSString* selectedItemTitle = [selectedItem title];

if ([selectedItemTitle isEqualTo: ... ]) { ... }
```

Note that comparing UI strings is a very bad idea. A slightest change in UI will immediately break your code, and you are preventing future localization. You should assign numeric or object values to each item using `-[NSMenuItem setTag:`] or `-[NSMenuItem setRepresentedObject:`] and use them to identify items instead.